# What can I learn from a Vector's Direction?

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

I have the following vectors
$\vec b=\left(\begin{matrix}-4\\
3
\end{matrix}\right)$  and $\left(\begin{matrix}x\\
y
\end{matrix}\right)$

Now we know that the length of the x,y vector is 1, and that it has the same  
direction as $\vec b$

The length teaches us $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=1$

What does the direction teach us ?

Comment: You can compute $x$ and $y$ from it. Rescaling the vector does not change the direction. So if you know that it has the same direction as $b$ and you know its length, then you get $x$ and $y$.

Comment: When $(x,y)$ has the same direction as $\vec b$ then $(x,y)=\lambda \vec b$ for some $\lambda>0$

Comment: The direction teaches you the ratio, $y/x$.

Comment: It teaches you all you need to know about $\left(\begin{matrix}x\\
y
\end{matrix}\right)$ namely that it is equal to  $\vec b/5=\left(\begin{matrix}-4/5\\
3/5
\end{matrix}\right)$.